# Get only one of a function's returned values

Tags: python, return-value

I have defined a function as:

```
def f():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = 7

    def g(x): 
         return x+2

    return a, b , c, g
```

I would like to know how to get only one of the value returned, without the other ones. For example If I am only interested in `c`, is there an alternative to:

```
a, b, c, g = f()
```

To get `c`?

Comment: Well, `_, _, c, _ = f()`...

Comment: `c = f()[2]`...?

Answer (score 2):

Python returns multiple values as a tuple. You can check this by doing

```
>>> type(f())
>>> <class 'tuple'>
```

As from your implementation we can assume that the `c` variable value always lies on the index `2` so  you can do

```
c_value = f()[2]
```